# AS3 movie instance turning null

Tags: actionscript-3, null, movieclip

I'm banging my head on what seems like a simple as3 problem. I have a flash chart that contains a series of buttons that go to different parts of the timeline on Roll_over.

so for example - the "Market maneuvers" button looks like this

```
marketManeuversButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, marketManeuversButtonReaction)
```

and the function it calls looks like this

```
function marketManeuversButtonReaction (event:MouseEvent):void{ gotoAndStop('18'); }
```

The problem is, when I mouseover that button (and many others), it goes to frame '18' and then throws this error:

> Error #1009 Cannot access a property or method of a null object
>   reference

[here is my flash file](http://hanadismail.com/14-778v2.fla)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: also, this doesn't happen to each and every button. Some of them lose the event listener when I leave a frame and some don't.

Answer (score 0):

When you change frame, flash recreated all objects in frame, and you loose all your data.

Yes, it's simple AS3 problem, just don't use a scene frames at all. Program all in classes, don't use any frames to code any logic except stop(), gotoAndStop(), gotoAndPlay().

In your problem, put all scene in movieclip, exclude control buttons from it to another movieclip and control scene movie clip with control movieclip >____<. It pegleg. Next time just do it right, don't use scene frames.

Comment: so are you saying that I should remove all scripting from the frames and use classes? 

or I should start over and not use the timeline at all? This is due in a couple of hours so starting over isn't really an option. Thanks.

Comment: Both. Remove all scripts from frames, and don't use timeline. You can fix your work moves clips from timeline inside to movieclip. But in future just use classes.